# CSS Specificity not applying when used on table row and cell

Tags: css, css-specificity

My understanding of [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) is that `tr.makeitred` should overrule `.makeitblue`.

So what am I missing that means in this case the `Blue` is still blue from `.makeitblue`... instead of being overridden by the higher specificity of `tr.makeitred`?

(Even adding `!important` to make it `color:red !important` doesn't do anything)

```css
tr.makeitred {
  color:red;
}
.makeitblue {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="makeitred">
      <td>Red</td>
      <td class="makeitblue">Blue</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: specificity apply only when both selectors target the same element, which is not the case here

Comment: Ah, that would explain it.  So is there a way to override the blue?